# iOS to Android encryption

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, encryption

I'm trying to convert some Swift code to Kotlin and I'm trying to obtain the result of the method **"prepareForMessage"** equivalent in Kotlin, however I'm stuck and I've tried changing the ways encryption is done.
Here is the Swift code:

```
public final func prepareForMessage(ToEncrypt: String) -> String {
    let EncryptionOutput = encrypt(ToEncrypt: ToEncrypt)
    let postString = "Payload=" + EncryptionOutput.Output + "&Key=" + EncryptionOutput.Key + "&IV=" + EncryptionOutput.IV
    return postString
}

public final func encrypt(ToEncrypt: String) -> (Output: String, Key: String, IV: String) {
    let Key = randomKey(64)
    let IV = randomKey(64)

    let KeyRSA = rsaEncrypt(ToEncrypt: Key)
    let IVRSA = rsaEncrypt(ToEncrypt: IV)
    
    var base64String = ""
    do {
        let KeyA: [UInt8] = Array(Key.utf8)
        let IVA: [UInt8] = Array(IV.utf8)
        let ToEncryptA: [UInt8] = Array(ToEncrypt.utf8)
        
        let KeySHA = Digest(algorithm: .sha256).update(byteArray: KeyA)?.final()
        let IVSHA = Digest(algorithm: .sha256).update(byteArray: IVA)?.final()
        
        let KeySHAData = dataFrom(byteArray: KeySHA!)
        let IVSHAData = dataFrom(byteArray: IVSHA!)
        let ToEncryptData = dataFrom(byteArray: ToEncryptA)
        
        let r = Rijndael(key: KeySHAData, mode: .cbc)
        let cipherData = r!.encrypt(data: ToEncryptData, blockSize: 32, iv: IVSHAData)
        
        base64String = cipherData!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        base64String = formatString(ToFormat: base64String)
    } catch { }
    print("b:\(base64String) , key:\(KeyRSA), iv:\(IVRSA)")
    return (base64String , KeyRSA, IVRSA)
}


public final func rsaEncrypt(ToEncrypt: String) -> String {
    let publicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC4uhj+t8KnN8UvLrTlZNk1gWl4\nEYBRYo5XqzWX4icrcG0oWr04qSyQ7tLnNP+mvcG/2OWr+rjddZ5Ikr00DF+HIeKM\n7SlmleWr4Etpg855ysUrDJPRvtYuyEteyeR4f5OVSl8bgyb1f//BHc4+v80xzqRn\nxnJlaB+0V4kO8hQwAQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
    let pubkey: String = publicKey
    var encryptedString = RSA.encryptString(ToEncrypt, publicKey: pubkey)!
    encryptedString = formatString(ToFormat: encryptedString)
    return encryptedString
}

public final func formatString(ToFormat: String) -> String {
    var FormatedString = ToFormat
    FormatedString = FormatedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "-")
    FormatedString = FormatedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "_")
    return FormatedString
}

public final func randomKey(_ n: Int) -> String {
    let a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
    
    var s = ""
    
    for _ in 0..<n
    {
        let r = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(a.count)))
        
        s += String(a[a.index(a.startIndex, offsetBy: r)])
    }
    
    return s
}
```

and this is the Kotlin code:

```
fun encrypt(ToEncrypt: String): Triple<String, String, String> {
    val keyString: String = generateRandomCryptographicKey()
    val ivString : String = generateRandomCryptographicKey()
    val key = rsaEncrypt(keyString)
    val iv = rsaEncrypt(ivString)

    try{
        val keyA = key.toByteArray()
        val ivA = iv.toByteArray()
        val toEncryptA = ToEncrypt.toByteArray()

        val keySHA : ByteArray = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(keyA)
        val ivSHA : ByteArray = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(ivA)
        //Cipher = Rijndael see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, SecretKeySpec(keySHA, "AES"), IvParameterSpec(ivSHA))
            
        val cipherText = cipher.doFinal(toEncryptA)
        val base64String: String = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText,Base64.DEFAULT)
        val payloadDigested = base64String.formatDigested()
        Timber.e("payload: $payloadDigested\n key: $key\n iv:$iv")
        return Triple(payloadDigested, key, iv)

        }catch (exception: Exception){
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }
        return Triple("payload",key, iv)
}

private fun rsaEncrypt(textToEncrypt: String): String {
    val publicKeyRaw =  "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC4uhj+t8KnN8UvLrTlZNk1gWl4\nEYBRYo5XqzWX4icrcG0oWr04qSyQ7tLnNP+mvcG/2OWr+rjddZ5Ikr00DF+HIeKM\n7SlmleWr4Etpg855ysUrDJPRvtYuyEteyeR4f5OVSl8bgyb1f//BHc4+v80xzqRn\nxnJlaB+0V4kO8hQwAQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
    val publicKey = publicKeyRaw.replace("\n", "")
            .replace("\\n","")
            .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
            .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
    val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    val keyBytes: ByteArray = Base64.decode(publicKey.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT)
    val spec = X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes)
    val fileGeneratedPublicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec)
    val rsaPub: RSAPublicKey = fileGeneratedPublicKey as RSAPublicKey
    val publicKeyModulus: BigInteger = rsaPub.modulus
    val publicKeyExponent: BigInteger = rsaPub.publicExponent

    val keyFactoryAlt = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    val pubKeySpec = RSAPublicKeySpec(publicKeyModulus, publicKeyExponent)
    val key = keyFactoryAlt.generatePublic(pubKeySpec) as RSAPublicKey

    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
    val cipherData: ByteArray =  cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt.toByteArray())
    return Base64.encodeToString(cipherData, Base64.DEFAULT)
}

private fun generateRandomCryptographicKey(n: Int = 64): String {
    val  a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
    val total = a.length-1
    var generated = ""
    for(i in 0 until n){
        generated+=a[Random.nextInt(IntRange(0,total))]
    }
    return generated
}
```

But when I go init I get an exception *invalidAlgorithmParameterException: expected IV length of 16 but was 32*

Comment: Seems to me that your Swift code isn't using AES-256, because AES-256 has a blocksize of 16 bytes. Perhaps it's using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256. You'll have to change either the Swift code or the Kotlin code so that both of them use the same algorithms.